# How to add arrowhead at end of Path using C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, path

By Below code, I am creating a curve.  I want an arrowHead at the end of curve?

```
PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();

// Create a figure.
PathFigure pathFigure1 = new PathFigure();
pathFigure1.StartPoint = new Point(From.X, From.Y);
pathFigure1.Segments.Add(
   new BezierSegment(
      new Point(intermidate.X, intermidate.Y),
      new Point(intermidate2.X/2, intermidate2.Y/2),
         new Point(To.X, To.Y),
       true /* IsStroked */ ));

myPathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure1);
myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
myPath.StrokeThickness = 4.0;
myPath.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Triangle;
myPath.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Triangle;

myPath.Data = myPathGeometry;
```

How to add arrow head at end of curve?

Please suggest a good approach by code.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing an arrow end on a Quadratic Bezier Segment using xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218077/drawing-an-arrow-end-on-a-quadratic-bezier-segment-using-xaml)

Comment: @Sinatr This is by Xmal. I want to achieve it by code